# Query column for data that cannot be converted to datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, type-conversion

I have an older table where a `datetime` column was built as a `varchar` and the form inserting data into this table was freeform with no validation/restrictions. I have corrected the form and now am set upon the task of normalizing the data. I need to query this column for all records that cannot be `CAST` as a `datetime`

Examples:

```
9/30/2008
9/30/13
august 2010
5/11
30SEP12
31-Mar-2011
2005
```

I have already cleaned up the `N/A` data to be `NULL` but am unsure of an efficient way of getting everything that would not be considered a valid date. Any hints or tricks or am I going to have to go through record by record to convert this column to a `datetime` data type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ISDATE` to determine records that aren't dates:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE isdate(OldDateField) = 0
```

You can use the query below to see which ones won't be dates:

```
SELECT isdate('9/30/2008')
SELECT isdate('9/30/13')
SELECT isdate('august 2010')
SELECT isdate('5/11')
SELECT isdate('30SEP12')
SELECT isdate('31-Mar-2011 2005')
```

Comment: You my friend are a lifesaver. Thank You! Also <3 your username.

Comment: Just one problem with this approach - if you come across a date like `05/06/2011`, `ISDATE()` will return true, but how will you know whether the user meant May 6 or June 5?

Comment: Four years later and this is still a brilliantly simple answer and solution to a problem loads of people must have on a regular basis...